# How to achieve Web Responsiveness for smaller width devices efficiently?

Tags: responsive-design

I want to know how can I achieve efficient responsiveness for smaller width devices (mobile phones), how can I be so sure about the styles that I have applied are gonna be well looking for all different screen sizes?

I have had tried Dev Tools of Google Chrome and I have been working with them since last 4 months but now when I am bit more focused on responsiveness of webs I can't have it helping me!!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried activating "Device Mode" in Chrome?

[image]

This allows you to preview what the site you're working on would look like on a number of predefined devices, with the option to add device definitions of your own:

[image]

You can read more about the "Device Mode" [in the official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode).

Comment: I've tried thiss but thiss is not working providing all devices' viewport sizes -

Comment: If you pick "Responsive" from the list you can enter whatever width & height you want.